# Creating A New App For Page

Tags: blogs, facebook-apps

I have a personal FB account, and from there I created a new page that tells about my blogs website. I downloaded a widget for my WordPress theme in my website, to make it possible for me to link the two accounts for auto updating. The widget requires that I provide an App ID and Secret through creating a New App. When I come to do this, FB will not allow me to choose to do it under my "added" page, but only with my personal account. Will this effect where my blog updates post to?

Also, if you could tell me what a namespace is and how I should go about deciding one, it would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to :

- Verify your account as a developer (via mobile phone or credit card)
- Add the developers app ( http://www.facebook.com/developers/ )
- Create a new application
- Retrieve your new applications app id and secret through the developers app.

You are only allowed to open an application with a personal verified Facebook account.  This is so that Facebook can track applications that have violated their [Terms of Service](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) back to "a real person".

With regard to the `app namespace`, this is a name that you choose for your application's URL on Facebook.  An application's URL looks something like this :
`https://apps.facebook.com/melissasGreatApp`

The namespace can be anything you choose (as long as it is not already occupied by some other application - Facebook will alert you if you choose a taken namespace).  It is similar to choosing a website name.  Choose something that is related somehow to your application.